# Selector :not(:last-child) not working with div child img tag?

Tags: html, css, image, selector

this is my html code!

```
<main>
        <section class="section-about">
            <div class="section-about__imagesDiv"> 
                <img src="http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/spitfire1.jpg" alt="#" class="test ">
                <img src="http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/spitfire1.jpg" alt="#" class="test ">
                <img src="http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/spitfire1.jpg" alt="#" class="test ">
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Here I have my css code and I don't understad why is not selecting the first two images and let the last one out, basically how is right now is not selecting nothing

```
.section-about__imagesDiv:not(:last-child) {

margin-top: 100rem;}
```

Thank you in advance! I spent two hours untill now but no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the container of the images. Assuming you want to give the images a margin try to use the following code:

```
.section-about__imagesDiv img{ margin-top: 100rem; }
```

This will select all images except the last.

```css
.section-about__imagesDiv img:not(:last-child) { margin-top: 100rem;}
```

```html
<main>
        <section class="section-about">
            <div class="section-about__imagesDiv"> 
                <img src="http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/spitfire1.jpg" alt="#" class="test ">
                <img src="http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/spitfire1.jpg" alt="#" class="test ">
                <img src="http://static.messynessychic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/spitfire1.jpg" alt="#" class="test ">
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rule you have written is targeting elements with the class `.section-about__imagesDiv` that are not the last child, not children within that `<div/>`. Because there is only one div with that class, that div is therefore the last child and causing your style to have no effect, even on the wrong element.

You want to target the images, for example;

```
.section-about__imagesDiv > .test:not(:last-child) {
    margin-top: 100rem;
}
```